# Defeat rabbitmq-server dpkg autostart

Tags: dpkg, rabbitmq

I need rabbitmq-server installed on Ubuntu. Rabbitmq-server tries to start itself on install, and on many dpkg and apt-get commands thereafter. (Having it run on install is intentional, according to the [instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#running-debian).) On this box, rabbitmq server can't start, and it takes about a minute to give up. I don't want to fix that. I want to make it not try to start whenever I run, say

```
apt-get install something-not-related-to-rabbitmq
```

When I do that, not only does it take an extraordinarily long time to install the package, but it also exits with `100`, even if the package itself installed fine. Here's a snippet of what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fortune
Reading package lists... Done

-- SNIP --

Unpacking fortunes-min (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.6.0-1) ...
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up librecode0:amd64 (3.6-21) ...
Setting up fortune-mod (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Setting up fortunes-min (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$ echo $?
100
```

I'd rather not uninstall it, as I do eventually plan to get around to using it. But frankly, I think it's a little bit nuts that it hijacks my dpkg, and I would appreciate some help killing that little misfeature with fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is to make the post-installation start a no-op. 
The `rabbitmq-server.postinst` is located in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, like all the other postinst scripts, and the jessie version contains the lines:

```
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server" ]; then
        update-rc.d rabbitmq-server defaults >/dev/null
        invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start || exit $?
fi
```

Just comment out that entire section, and nothing will happen. Or you can try just commenting out `invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start || exit $`.